# Error al scrapear datos de Fotocasa con python

Tags: python, scrapy

Intento scrapear los títulos de los locales comerciales de Valencia en Fotocasa y me devuelve el siguiente error.

```
# Code follows:
allowed_domain = "fotocasa.es"
real_base_url = "https://www.fotocasa.es"

start_urls = ["https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/locales/valencia-capital/valencia-ciudad/l/%?latitude=39.47389303025584&longitude=-0.37903572198717134&combinedLocationIds=724,19,46,358,0,46250,144,0,0&gridType=3" % (page_number) for page_number in range(1,63)]

# Crawl Search Page Results
def parse(self, response):

    print (response.url)
    # Main Page Parsing
    houses_snippets = response.xpath("//h3[@class='re-Card-title']")
    for house_snippet in houses_snippets:
        house_object_id = house_snippet.xpath("@href").extract()[0]
        house_link = urlparse.urljoin(self.real_base_url, house_object_id)
        request = scrapy.Request(house_link, callback=self.parse_house_post)
        yield request
```

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      2 real_base_url = "https://www.fotocasa.es"
      3 
----> 4 start_urls = ["https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/locales/valencia-capital/valencia-ciudad/l/%?latitude=39.47389303025584&longitude=-0.37903572198717134&combinedLocationIds=724,19,46,358,0,46250,144,0,0&gridType=3" % (page_number) for page_number in range(1,63)]
      5 
      6 # Crawl Search Page Results

in (.0)
      2 real_base_url = "https://www.fotocasa.es"
      3 
----> 4 start_urls = ["https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/locales/valencia-capital/valencia-ciudad/l/%?latitude=39.47389303025584&longitude=-0.37903572198717134&combinedLocationIds=724,19,46,358,0,46250,144,0,0&gridType=3" % (page_number) for page_number in range(1,63)]
      5 
      6 # Crawl Search Page Results

ValueError: unsupported format character '?' (0x3f) at index 79

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la bandera de reemplazo para el formato que trata de usar es `%?`que no es válida, te falta el tipo de conversión que es obligatorio, `%s`, `%i` o `%d` te valdrían en este caso:

```
start_urls = ["https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/locales/valencia-capital/valencia-ciudad/l/%s?latitude=39.47389303025584&longitude=-0.37903572198717134&combinedLocationIds=724,19,46,358,0,46250,144,0,0&gridType=3" % (page_number) for page_number in range(1,63)]
```

No obstante el formateo de cadena con % heredado de C se considera en la práctica obsoleto, usa `f-strings` o en su defecto `str.format()`/`format()`

```
start_urls = [
    ("https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/locales/valencia-capital/"
     f"valencia-ciudad/l/{page_number}?"
     "latitude=39.47389303025584&longitude=-0.37903572198717134&"
     "combinedLocationIds=724,19,46,358,0,46250,144,0,0&gridType=3"
     ) for page_number in range(1,63)
    ]
```